# How to loop a musicsequence IOS from beginning?

Tags: ios, loops, coremidi

I have a MIDI file loop fine as long as it loops the entire track. The problem is that I'd like to loop from the beginning to a specified length - say 2 beats out of four. But looping from the beginning, not from the end as described in Apple's documentation(re: MusicTrackLoopInfo): "The point in a music track, *measured in beats from the end* of the music track, at which to begin playback during looped playback"

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the answer but... Maybe set the track length instead of the loop point. So set track length to your desired loop length and loop indefinitely.

Comment: I have same problem, and if I try to change the musicTrack property Lenght does not change if the music track already has midi notes inside. Other ideas? did someone find a solution?